# DJI Thermal SDK can't open xt2 camera thermal image

Tags: dji-sdk

I have downloaded the official windows DJI Thermal SDK, and I can successfully use the exe on sample image. But failed to open my DJI XT2 camera's thermal rjpeg output.

```
D:\test\dji_thermal_sdk_v1.2_20211209\utility\bin\windows\release_x64>dji_irp.exe -s D:/Dropbox/dji/selected/999431646940552000.jpg -a measure -o measure.raw
DIRP API version number : 0x12
DIRP API magic version  : bb44858
R-JPEG file path : D:/Dropbox/dji/selected/999431646940552000.jpg
ERROR: create R-JPEG dirp handle failed
Test done with return code -7
```

The sample image in XTS folder has a image naming like DJI_0001_R.jpg. But my image name is 999431646940552000.jpg like below, is this supported by DJI Thermal SDK?

[image]

(I cam verify my rjpeg image is correct, since it can be opened using FlIR thermal Studio starter.)

Comment: Received official reply that xt2 image is obsolete and is not supported by DJI Thermal SDK.

Answer (score 0):

the DJI thermal SDK doesn't support XT2 camera. Supported products are:

- XTS
- H20T series
- Mavic 2 Enterprise Advanced

Comment: I am having the same problem and I am using the thermal data from the DJI MAVIC M3T. Have you found some solution?

Comment: I am having a similar problem.  Any solutions to this issue?